# infinite sum derivative of $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n/n$ where $-1<x<1$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

can't seem to approach this question about derivative of an infinite sum.

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n/n$ where $-1<x<1$

Then $f'(x)$ is?

Answer is $1/(1-x)$ for some reason

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n/n$, then $f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ when $|x|<1$.

Comment: Why does sum to infinity from n=1 of x^n/x = x^n from n=0 to infinity? And how does the latter converge to 1/(1-x)? Sorry my analysis is weak since i specialized in acturial stats for my undergraduate. something to do with power rule convergence?

Comment: Look at the indexes of the terms. If it helps, you may want to write a few terms out. For proof that it equals $\frac{1}{1-x}$, you may want to google infinite geometric series. Khan academy has some great videos about this topic.